# Multiple file upload with list of file names with individual remove option - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filereader

I am working on a HTML and JavaScript multiple file upload screen.

This is the present code for my form. (The file upload works nicely on the back-end. its the front end I need help with. So I am only providing the code in the blade file)

```
<form action= {{ route('complaints.post.step.four') }} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="cell">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputFile">Select file</label>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="inputFile" multiple >          
    </div>
    <div class="cell" id="previews"></div>

        <button type="submit" class="button secondary">Submit complaint</button>

</form>
```

and the script is

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        var images = function(input, imgPreview) {
    
            if (input.files) {
                var filesAmount = input.files.length;
    
                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
    
                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        $($.parseHTML("<img class='pic'>")).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(imgPreview);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
    
        };
    
        $('#inputFile').on('change', function() {
            images(this, '#previews');
        });
            
            //clear the file list when image is clicked
        $('body').on('click','img',function(){
            $('#inputFile').val("");
            $('#previews').html("");
    
        });
    });
```

The present code provides a preview section; where if the user uploads a image is visible. But if the user uploads any other type of document then that particular file looks like a missing image icon.

[image]

(In the above screenshot the user chose to upload a docx file and a image file. The docx file is inside red circle and the image file can be seen beside that. )

The user of this form are allowed to upload any kind of file including but not limited to docx; pdf; image; audio; video. So instead of a preview screen I want the names of the chosen files to be listed below the upload button (e.g; abc.docx ; xyz.jpg ) along with an individual remove(x) option beside each of them

To list the name of the files I have Tried the following

```
$('document').ready(function() {
 $('input:file').change(function(){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.files.length ; i++){
      var fileName = this.files[i].name;
      $('.filenames').append('<div class="name">' + fileName + '</div>');
    }
 });
});
```

it gives me the list of file names but still i dont have the remove option for individual files. **How do i remove individual file from that screen**

[image]

TIA

Comment: Check the file extension before you attempt to display it. Don't use an img tag if the extension isn't one you recognise as an image type, instead just output the filename. It should be the first thing you do in the `for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {` loop, because you might not even need the `FileReader` if it's not an image. Have you tried anything? This has nothing to do with PHP, btw.

Comment: I have edited the question tag and removed php from there

Comment: i have removed the image tag. but how to display the names of the file?

Comment: Any way you like. Maybe add a `<span` or something with the name in, instead of the `<img`? Or are you asking how to retrieve the name of the file from the `input.files` array? It wasn't really clear exactly what the issue is.

Comment: I edited my question and added the piece of code I tried.

Comment: Thanks. So `i dont have the remove option for individual files` is actually the issue, not how to display the names? Well you'd need to add a HTML button alongside each name (or image, depending on the file type) and bind it  (when clicked) to a function which removes the div or img tag. Since you'd be dynamically creating the buttons, taking advantage of jQuery's delegated event handling functionality would probably make sense here.